Azure logic apps encode left bracket in json query param names to ~2. How can I rewrite with concat and/or replace functions?
I need a method to overcome logic apps' encoding.  See "~2" in place of "[" below:
    "parameters~20]~2field]": "date_start",
    "parameters~20]~2value]": "@variables('dateStart')",
    "parameters~20]~2operator]": ">=",
    "parameters~20]~2include_type]": "AND",
    "parameters~21]~2field]": "date_start",
    "parameters~21]~2value]": "@variables('dateEnd')",
    "parameters~21]~2operator]": "<=",
    "parameters~21]~2include_type]": "AND",
    "parameters~22]~2field]": "qty_open",
    "parameters~22]~2value]": "0",
    "parameters~22]~2operator]": ">",
    "parameters~22]~2include_type]": "AND",
    "parameters~23]~2field]": "credit_status",
    "parameters~23]~2value]": "Approved",
    "parameters~23]~2operator]": "=",
    "parameters~23]~2include_type]": "AND",
    "pagination~2page_size]": body('MyCompany_V3_API_Vendor_Authentication')?'page_size']",
"pagination~2last_id]": "@variables('last_id')"

I tried various ways of concatenating the parts of param names with logicapp/json compatible functions to convert the encoding.  I also tried @replace.  I always seem to be running into the problem of single quotes getting along with double quotes.

Can you share the expected response you want ?

You can make the given changes to get the expected response.
{
    "@{replace('parameters~20]~2field]', '~2', '[')}": "date_start",
    "@{replace('parameters~20]~2value]', '~2', '[')}": "ABC",
    "@{replace('parameters~20]~2operator]', '~2', '[')}": ">=",
    "@{replace('parameters~20]~2include_type]', '~2', '[')}": "AND"
}

You will get below response.


Thanks for your answer, Mr. Afrin.  I'm sorry that I was asleep (Eastern US) when you answered and didn't see your request for my expected response.  Unfortunately, when I implemented your solution I discovered that azure also considers the @ sign a special character and escapes it by doubling it.  @ becomes @@ when I save the app, and the json response is an error from the api.  So I created a string var set to @, and am trying to concat it with the replace function in the param name.  No success so far.  Any ideas?  Thanks again!
